# How to parse websocket in nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing, websocket, tcp

Sending message using web socket send function.

```
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
ws.send(msg);
```

I'm getting packets in the on("data") event as `hellworldhelloworldhelloworld`...

How do I separate one packet from one another?

Comment: maybe you wanna include a break line in the end of your `message` (assuming it is a simple string)?

Comment: no I am implementing websocket so put custom delimiter wont help

Comment: a break line it is not a custom delimiter. Can you place some code of your consumer?